# flask sqlite3 security issue

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlite

I have written a Flask application in which user answers 5 questions in 5 different pages and his/her answers are sent to the `database.db` using sqlite3.

After deploying the application on Ubuntu, I received an error stating that database is read only. so I changed the permission by `chmod 777`. Then the problem was solved.

But I have read many recommendations about not using `chmod 777`  under any circumstances. (Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277419/python-flask-web-app-security))

So what should I do?
How can I write data received from user to database safely?

```
#a sample part of my code:

@app.route('/g2', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def k2():
    z1= request.form['z1']
    z2= request.form['z2']
    con = sql.connect("/var/www/FlaskApp/database.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("UPDATE hoc SET z2=? WHERE id=?", (z2, z1))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

Comment: You should use an ORM or somehow make the changes in memory and commit 'em to the actual database at once

Answer (score 2):

This is not a programming problem.

It is **absolutely essential** to understand the concept of Unix (Linux) file ownership and permissions - including the umask value and directory permissions. There are thousands of tutorials.

The easiest way is to store the database in its own directory. The DB file(s) should be owned by the same user account used to run the flask app. It is your account during development and http server's account in production.

The most restrictive file mode for the DB file(s) is 0600 (file modes are octal numbers).